# ASCII String Encoding issue with special characters

Tags: iphone, ios, utf-8, ascii

In my app i am using ASCII string encoding to convert NSString to NSData. For the below case i am unable to convert the string to data as it contains some special characters. I am able to encode properly using UTF 8 but i need to use ascii as  server is also configured to use ASCII.

NSData *ldata=[@"CASTAÑO" dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

Please help me in fixing this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to encode and decode the data using NSISOLatin1StringEncoding even though the server is configured to use ASCII.

NSData *ldata=[@"CASTAÑO" dataUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];

The special character 'Ñ' is a extended ascii character which will not be encoded by ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want "CASTAÑO" to be converted to "CASTANO" in your NSData?

Use [dataUsingEncoding:allowLossyConversion:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/dataUsingEncoding%3aallowLossyConversion%3a)

As in:

```
NSData *ldata=[@"CASTAÑO" dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                       allowLossyConversion:YES];
```

Comment: Is there is any way send CASTAÑO itself instead of CASTANO as on the server side they are looking for CASTAÑO itself for seraching in the database

Comment: Not in ASCII, no (Ñ isn't an ASCII character).

Comment: Note that Ñ is extended-ASCII (165), so that raises the question of what the server really wants. If it demands 7-bit ASCII, then there is no way to send it an Ñ. If it wants 8-bit extended ASCII, then UTF-8 will match that for legal extended ASCII characters. The only place you should have problems is when the character is outside of the extended ASCII character set (which won't work for you anyway).

Answer (score 0):

How about transferring your data using MIME?
MIME is the standard way to encode various file types using ASCII characters.
It is normally used to send non-ASCII email using SMTP protocol that does not support any non-ASCII data.

There are categories which extend NSData/NSString to encode data using MIME (which would result in ASCII characters.) I do not think it is an instant solution for you, but according to your constraint (ASCII-only server), MIME should be the best solution.

See: 
http://www.mulle-kybernetik.com/software/EDFrameworks/download.html#EDMessage
and
http://bitbucket.org/portablek/mimekit/overview